# Connecting ROKU to Vpn/Proxy while all other home computers connect normally

Tags: networking, proxy, lan

I was wondering if its possible to have one LAN IP access the web through a proxy while the rest are untouched. Since I am in Canada I would like to be able to use my Roku through a US proxy.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In general, yes this is possible - though I doubt you can with a stock E2100 router. I would look into routing platforms like pfSense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to how to connect ROKU to US VPN/Proxy while having all other home computers work normally

Need 2 routers though. Can get them cheap off ebay. One must be able to have embeddable proxy/VPN settings in it.

---

- Connect first router to cable modem normally.
- Connect 2nd router's WAN port to one of the LAN ports of first router.
- Create a Wifi name/password on router 1
- Create a different Wifi name/password on router 2
- First router: open DMZ on the LAN port used by 2nd router
- First router: Asign a static LAN IP to the LAN port used by 2nd router
- 2nd Router: Use a different subnet. For example, if first router is 192.168.1.X, have 2nd router be 192.168.2.X
- In 2nd router, set up proxy/VPN settings
- In ROKU, connect to 2nd router that is now using the proxy to connect to a US server.
- In all other home computers, connect normally to your first router.